Condition in python lists comprehensions
friends-coders! Help with condition in lists comprehensions at python code, please. Where are mistake in that syntax?
matrix = [
  [matrix[i][j] = '.' if matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0 else matrix[i][j] = '*' for i in range(int(col))] 
  for j in range(int(row))
] 

Don’t know how to resolve this problem.

I believe the problem is matrix[i][j] = '.'.  You can't have a plain assignment as the inner part of a list comprehension.

Although you didn't provide a description of the desired result, it's likely that you were after this:
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

col = 3
row = 3

matrix = [
  ['.' if matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0 else '*' for i in range(int(col))]
  for j in range(int(row))
]

print(matrix)

Output:
[['*', '.', '*'], ['.', '*', '.'], ['*', '.', '*']]

It generates a new matrix with a '.' in place of every even value and a '*' in place of every odd one, and assigns the result to matrix, overwriting the original data.
A few remarks on the code you shared:

You were assigning a newly created list to matrix, but also had assignment statements (i.e. [matrix[i][j] =) in the list comprehension, which does not work.
You have int(col) and int(row) suggesting that these were not int values to begin with; in my example they are, but since you provided no code defining them, some guesswork is required and I left them in. I assumed they represented the size of the nested list matrix.

As user @Chris indicates in the comments, a more concise solution to your problem would be:
matrix = [['.' if x % 2 == 0 else '*' for x in row] for row in matrix]

This avoids the use of indices altogether and will also work for nested lists that don't form a rectangular matrix.

This would be better without the explicit indexing at all. [['.' if x % 2 == 0 else '*' for x in row] for row in matrix]

Yes but I decided to just remove the excess code from OP, instead of rewriting it into a better solution overall.

I’m very excuse me in front of you for my code. But I’m very thanks for your answer.

You're welcome - give @Chris 's comment an upvote as well, if you were looking for the shorter answer.

The assignments in your conditional expression are clearly wrong.
You may want to use the walrus operator (:=) instead. More details would be needed about what you're actually trying to do to determine if this would be helpful. Keep in mind that list comprehensions are generally only to be used for generating new lists rather than modifying existing lists. Using them to replace a loop strikes me as distinctly "un-Pythonic."
